# Submitting actions for unreleased iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook-opengraph

The Open Graph "Submit for Approval" documentation page says that the team evaluating the Actions will follow our instructions to trigger them. Our iOS app uploads a document to our backend server, and then posts the action with the unique url that was just generated.

What's the best way to get our actions approved by Facebook, given that they can only be triggered from an iOS app that's not available in the app store yet?

Comment: Could you set up a test page on your server which does the same backend functions which would be triggered from the iOS app?

Comment: I can add a button on the generated pages to trigger the same action easily enough (it would be removed prior to our release). Would that be enough to evaluate it?

Comment: I can confirm that having a test page on your server that simulates the same behavior and explaining that to Facebook works. We just did that for our app.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is simple as stated on the comments.

1. Create a web app that simulates the same behavior used by the iOS
   App to post to Open Graph.
2. Give that link to Facebook and explain them your case.

In my case a previous version of the app (that didn't use Open Graph API) was already published so I sent them a link to that App explaining that this is an additional feature.

I suggest in your case sending a video of the app if you don't have a previous version already published.