# Documenting Native iOS Only Open Graph Action for Submission to Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, submission

My FB app is iOS only at this time.  I tried the approach described here
[Submitting Open Graph Actions for an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644259/submitting-open-graph-actions-for-an-ios-app)
and created a webpage with screenshots to document the user experience.

Facebook has responded by saying I need to show how the app works for the Auth Dialog Preview User.  I don't know how to log in to my iOS app with that user.  I know it works for canvas apps, does it ever work for native mobile apps?

I've filed this bug in the hope of getting more information:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/413755695354708

I hope I don't have to build a canvas app as described here
[Submitting actions for unreleased iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930044/submitting-actions-for-unreleased-ios-app)
in order to get my action approved.

Comment: I could repro this. Stay tuned to the bug report.

Comment: Facebook just approved the action without the use of Auth Dialog Preview User.  The webpage with screenshots and descriptions was enough.